# php pdo json encode array print

Tags: php, json

When I pull data from the hello database, it just writes the first line, not the other lines, what could be the reason?
I did not know much about php json but did not get any results.

**İD 88 NOT FOUND**

**database print **

```
[{"title":"facebook","contact":"facebook adres"},
{"title":"twitter","contact":"twitter adres"}]
```

**database data**

```
id:87 [{"title":"facebook","contact":"facebook adres"},
    {"title":"twitter","contact":"twitter adres"}]

id:88
    [{"title":"instagram","contact":"instagram adres"},
    {"title":"google","contact":"google adres"}]
```

**database function**

```
function menu($menu_title)
{
    global $db;
    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM menu WHERE menu_title = :menu_title');
    $query->execute([
        'menu_title' => $menu_title
    ]);
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($result) {
        $data = [];
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            $data += json_decode($value['menu_content'], true);
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**socialmedia foreach**

```
 <?php foreach (menu('sosyalmedya') as $key => $menu): ?>
 
<?= $menu['title'] ?><br>
<?= $menu['contact'] ?><br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[image: database data]

[image: database print]

Comment: If you do `print_r($result);` after fetchAll, do you have all results?

Comment: When you use `[0]` after the `json_decode()`, this is only accessing the first element from the data.

Comment: how can i edit this all right?

Comment: Loop over all the elements of the decoded JSON, not just the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only returning the first element of each JSON array. Append the whole array to the result.

```
        foreach ($result as $value) {
            $data = array_merge($data, json_decode($value['menu_content'], true));
        }
```

BTW, don't use `SELECT *` if you only want the `menu_content` column. Use `SELECT menu_content`.

Comment: Why is that a problem? Aren't they nested in the JSON?

Comment: it worked that way but it doesn't show when it's a 2nd line

Comment: Sounds like you need to use nested loops in the code that displays the HTML for the menu.

Comment: Can you help ? Barmar

Comment: Update the question to show what it looks like with submenus. And then show what you want the result to look like.

Comment: submenus no problem when you do it shows only one line

Comment: I just shared above, so your code just prints id 87, not other ids

Comment: Are you saying that each ID in the database should be a menu, and the elements of that JSON array should be submenus?